# How can I make a figure that has two x-axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to make a figure like this by using python. I drew the figure by using excel.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are going to have to build something like two plots and use the x-axis for one of them to be this secondary axis. There are other features in your plot like setting the labels for the ticks and their positions. The following example plays a bit with each of these elements so you should be able to adapt to your problem:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = ax1.twiny()

# Add some extra space for the second axis at the bottom
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
ax1.set_xticks([1,2,4,5,7,8])
ax1.set_xlim(0,9)
ax1.set_xticklabels(('2015','2016','2015','2016','2015','2016'))
ax2.spines["bottom"].set_position(("axes", -0.15))
ax2.xaxis.set_ticks_position("bottom")
ax2.spines["bottom"].set_visible(True)
ax2.set_xticks([1.5,4.5,7.5])
ax2.set_xticklabels(('1','2','3'))
ax2.set_xlim(0,9)

b1 = np.random.randint(0,100,6)
b2 = np.random.randint(0,100,6)
b3 = np.random.randint(0,100,6)
plt.bar(np.array([1,2,4,5,7,8])-0.4,b1,color='blue')
plt.bar(np.array([1,2,4,5,7,8])-0.4,b2,color='orange',bottom=b1)
plt.bar(np.array([1,2,4,5,7,8])-0.4,b3,color='yellow',bottom=b1+b2)

plt.show()
```

, the result is this:

[image: Two axis in a stacked bar plot in matplotlib]